# move API call from controller to model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am making a Book Club app. Users can upload books that they would like to read along with others. I'm bringing in the book info from Google Books Api and currently have the API call in the controller. I know this is ugly and unrailsy but am having trouble making it work from the model. What would you suggest as the best refactor to make this cleaner?

new.html.erb -from books

```
  <%= form_for :book, url: books_path do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <h1 class="text-center">Add A Book</h1>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <%= f.text_field :title, required: true, class: "form-control" %><br>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="genre">Genre</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <%= f.select :genre, [["Sci-fi", "Sci-fi"], ["Fantasy", "Fantasy"], ["Comic", "Comic"], ["Manga", "Manga"]], class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= f.submit "Create Book", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

books_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  find_book
  redirect_to root_path
end

require "openssl"
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

def find_book
  tempBook = params[:book][:title]
  tempGenre = params[:book][:genre]
  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + tempBook + "&key=secret_key"
  uri = URI(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  book_data = JSON.parse(response)    
  b = Book.new
  b.user_id = @user.id
  b.title = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["title"]
  b.genre = tempGenre
  b.author = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["authors"][0]
  b.publisher =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["publisher"]
  b.publication_date =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]
  b.synopsis =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["description"]
  b.image = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"]
  @book = b.save
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews

  def set_user(user)
    self.user_id = user.id 
    self.save    
  end

end
```

It works this way, but is ugly and I should hide my key, instead of leaving it open.

I tried putting the function in model and declaring the titles and genres as variables in the show method, but they weren't passed into the model so it didn't work.

Thanks!

Here's the code I tried, but it didn't work. the @tempBook is nil so it messes up the model. I'm assuming that's cause the model is running prior to getting the variable?

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews

  def set_user(user)
    self.user_id = user.id 
    self.save    
  end

  require "net/http"
  require "json"

  require "openssl"
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  def self.find_book
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + @tempBook + "&key=SECRET_KEY"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    book_data = JSON.parse(response)    
    b = Book.new
    b.user_id = @user.id
    b.title = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["title"]
    b.genre = @tempGenre
    b.author = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["authors"][0]
    b.publisher =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["publisher"]
    b.publication_date =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]
    b.synopsis =  book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["description"]
    b.image = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"]
    @book = b.save
  end

end
```

books_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @tempBook = params[:book][:title]
    @tempGenre = params[:book][:genre]
    @user = current_user
    Book.find_book
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: Can you please give us a bit more info on what "didn't work"? Can you show us the code you tried, also tell us what you observed (what was the error message exactly)? We can better help you make it work once we see the actual code (Note: don't put code in comments as the formatting is dreadful and hard to follow - edit your question and put it there) :)

Comment: Ah yes... so the reason why `@tempbook` doesn't work is that you shouldn't be using `@variable`s unless you know what they are ;)
They're great for passing variables to views form the controller - but otherwise you should just use actual method-arguments. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: I thought you used instance variables to move variables outside of their scope, but that they're still scoped in their class so not a global variable? But yeah, the concept of scope is still something i screw up

Comment: @Taryn East I switched to method arguments and it worked great!! Thanks, simple solution!

Comment: That is something that is *possible* to do... but really considered bad practice to do it... the normal way to pass variables is as arguments to methods - wherever possible. "magic global variables" have a way of breaking in new and unexpected ways. Plus they just appear out of nowhere and you don't know where they come from... better to pass things as arguments because you can follow them up the chain of calling methods and find where to set them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 to simplify code and make it more readable:

```
book_data = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]
# then you can write the shorter version:
b.title = book_data["title"] # etc
```

Step 2: secret keys are often best served as environment variables
Google for how to set up an environment variable on your platform.

The way to use it would be:

```
# Note that I've also added 'string interpolation' here
# (google that phrase to find out more)
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{tempBook}&key=#{ENV['BOOK_FIND_SECRET_KEY']}"
```

Note: these are small things to change.. I'd like to help more, but need more detail on what went wrong when you tried it out in the model (see comments for questions).

Step 3 `@variables` shouldn't be used (except when they should).

`@variables` are special... we use them in the controller to pass values to the view - that's because there's a kind of magic handover of data from controllers to views. But in all the rest of our ruby code - it's better to pass data as actual arguments to methods. eg if your book model has a method called `find_book` - instead of using `@tempBook`, you'd have an argument called `book_name` or similar. I'd also break that one big method up into smaller ones - each of which does one specific thing. Here's an example that just modifies your existing code:

```
# Note: generally it's accepted practice to put these includes
# at the top of the file outside of the class definition
require "net/http"
require "json"

require "openssl"

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Store the secret key in this constant so you don't have to 
  # keep typing the ENV-var name each time you use it
  SECRET_KEY = ENV['BOOK_FETCH_SECRET_KEY']

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews

  # I don't know what this is, so I've left it...
  # but it probably shoudln't go here...
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  # Make the book-url into a method - abstract out this complexity 
  # so the code for the main find_book method is much easier to read.
  # Notice how we pass in the book_name as an argument
  def self.book_url(book_name)
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{book_name}&key=#{SECRET_KEY}"
  end

  # Fetching the book via the URL is kind of a stand-alone thing to do
  # so it's easy to turn it into a method - that just accepts the 
  # book title, and returns the parsed book data
  def self.fetch_book_data(book_name)
    uri = URI(book_url(book_name))
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    JSON.parse(response)    
  end

  # and here's what's left for find_book
  # note how we name and use the arguments
  def self.find_book(user, book_name, genre)
    book_data = fetch_book_data(book_name)
    the_book = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]
    b = Book.new
    b.user_id = user.id
    b.title = the_book["title"]
    b.genre = genre
    b.author = the_book["authors"][0]
    b.publisher =  the_book["publisher"]
    b.publication_date =  the_book["publishedDate"]
    b.synopsis =  the_book["description"]
    b.image = the_book["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"]
    b.save
    # return the new book at the end of the method
    b
  end    
end
```

Now in the controller, we can call this code very simply:

```
def find_book
  # We just call the method on Book - passing in our params as the arguments
  @book = Book.find_book(current_user, params[:book][:title], params[:book][:genre])
end
```

Note: I really like the other Answer's idea of having a GoogleBook class that does the fetching - you can do that and put his fetching code into `fetch_book_data` (or equivalent) for better separation of concerns.

Comment: those little changes will clean it up a lot, thanks!

Comment: I'm just starting to figure out how to use environment variables, so I need to read up more on it.

Comment: ` OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` that's a hack I found because there's something wrong with a security certificate or something, I forget what exactly, but it messes with API calls and that line fixes it. I should probably sort out the issue, but haven't gotten around to it ...

Comment: Taryn East do you have any thoughts on storing secrete keys in yml files vs environment variables?

Comment: yaml files go into your github yes? which means your secrets are all over github... I prefer environment variables so you don't have that extra point of security to keep an eye on.

Comment: i've been struggling with hiding my key. I've been trying to do it by setting environment variables in a yml file in the config folder and then gitignoring it, but I must be doing something wrong as it never knows what the variable is. Part of me thinks it's kind of pointless. Any one can get a google API key for free, so why would you take the time to steal someone elses free key? It seems kinda pointless

Comment: Anyone can get a google API key.. but if you have trade secrets in your google drive, then you want to protect *your* key (or alternatively if you have keys that access your client's data etc etc)

Answer (score 5):

You should extract the google code out to some class that goes in the `lib` directory, the places the instantiation of an instance of that class into the book model then call the `find_book` method there. You can put the configurations keys for the api into a `yml` file.

```
#lib/google_book.rb
class GoogleBook
  def initialize(info)
  end

  def find_book
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + tempBook + "&key=secret_key"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    book_data = JSON.parse(response) 
    #rest of code
  end
end

#book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews

  def set_user(user)
    self.user_id = user.id 
    self.save    
  end

  def retrieve_google_book
    google_book = GoogleBook.new(some_params)
    google_book.find_book
  end

end
```

Comment: I was under the impression that database stuff should go in models, I haven't used lib at all. Will it have access to the form data from the index.html that is bringing in the initial title value, or should I be storing that value in another way? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't I need to also call `retrieve_google_book` in the create method? like `Book.retrieve_google_book`. Although when I tried that t said GoogleBook is an uninitialized constant

Comment: Yes you would have to still call the `retrieve_google_book` method from in the controller. the key point is you want to encapsulate the `API` inside a class so that you don't have your code littered with calls to an external service. That way if you ever change the `API` you use or if there is a breaking change you only have to go one place to fix/update it. The lib folder is a place where people normally store general purpose classes, it has the tendency to turn into a bit of a project junk draw so be disciplined with what you put in there.

Comment: that's a good idea, because my next step is to implement a comics API call that does the same thing, but autoloads info about comics if the genre is comics instead of books. Part of me wants to make a comics model, as it will have some different attributes that books won't have, but I'd be displaying the comics in the books view that's all ready set up so it seems easier to just add more elements to the book model, even if they end up being nil, if they don't apply to their specific type.I was thinking I'd put the conditional logic in the model too, but it might make more sense to try the lib